# how to roll-up milli-second tick data to one minute level

Tags: r

I have the following df which is at tick level:

```
aud_tick <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                aud_time = c("2018-02-25 21:55:38.098", "2018-02-25 21:55:38.398",
                             "2018-02-25 21:55:41.099",
                             "2018-02-25 21:55:41.398", "2018-02-25 21:55:41.700",
                             "2018-02-25 21:55:42.000", "2018-02-25 21:55:57.308",
                             "2018-02-25 21:55:57.907", "2018-02-25 21:55:57.908",
                             "2018-02-25 21:56:17.418", "2018-02-25 21:56:17.420",
                             "2018-02-25 21:56:18.019", "2018-02-25 21:56:21.621",
                             "2018-02-25 21:56:21.624", "2018-02-25 21:56:47.888",
                             "2018-02-25 21:56:55.696", "2018-02-25 21:56:59.749",
                             "2018-02-25 21:56:59.750", "2018-02-25 21:57:00.349",
                             "2018-02-25 21:57:00.351"),
                aud_pair = c("AUD/USD", "AUD/USD", "AUD/USD", "AUD/USD", "AUD/USD",
                             "AUD/USD", "AUD/USD", "AUD/USD", "AUD/USD",
                             "AUD/USD", "AUD/USD", "AUD/USD", "AUD/USD", "AUD/USD",
                             "AUD/USD", "AUD/USD", "AUD/USD", "AUD/USD", "AUD/USD",
                             "AUD/USD"),
                 aud_bid = c(0.78461, 0.78461, 0.78429, 0.78429, 0.78418, 0.78418, 0.78429,
                             0.78418, 0.78418, 0.78429, 0.78429, 0.78418,
                             0.78418, 0.78418, 0.78417, 0.78417, 0.78429, 0.78429,
                             0.78445, 0.78445),
                 aud_ask = c(0.78426, 0.78426, 0.78367, 0.78367, 0.78359, 0.78359, 0.78367,
                             0.78359, 0.78359, 0.78367, 0.78367, 0.78359,
                             0.78359, 0.78359, 0.7835, 0.7835, 0.78358, 0.78358,
                             0.78368, 0.78368)
            )
```

I would like to roll-up the data to one minute level having these details within that one minute window:

- aud_bid_high
- aud_bid_low
- aud_ask_higk
- aud_ask_low

Alternatively, would anyone know how to round the time to the:

- nearest 10 seconds - 21:55:38.098 to 21:55:40 or 21:55:30

I'm completely out of ideas, I've tried several approaches but to no avail.

Any ideas to help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used:
`lubridate::floor_date`

there are a number of options for rounding-up time scales, from seconds all the way up to year

Answer (score 0):

When you format the datum to a proper format, it rounds to seconds. You can split on that and do whatever aggregations (mean, max, min...) you please.

```
aud_tick$aud_time <- as.POSIXct(aud_tick$aud_time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
split(aud_tick, f = aud_tick$aud_time)

$`2018-02-25 21:55:38`
             aud_time aud_pair aud_bid aud_ask
1 2018-02-25 21:55:38  AUD/USD 0.78461 0.78426
2 2018-02-25 21:55:38  AUD/USD 0.78461 0.78426

$`2018-02-25 21:55:41`
             aud_time aud_pair aud_bid aud_ask
3 2018-02-25 21:55:41  AUD/USD 0.78429 0.78367
4 2018-02-25 21:55:41  AUD/USD 0.78429 0.78367
5 2018-02-25 21:55:41  AUD/USD 0.78418 0.78359

$`2018-02-25 21:55:42`
             aud_time aud_pair aud_bid aud_ask
6 2018-02-25 21:55:42  AUD/USD 0.78418 0.78359

$`2018-02-25 21:55:57`
             aud_time aud_pair aud_bid aud_ask
7 2018-02-25 21:55:57  AUD/USD 0.78429 0.78367
8 2018-02-25 21:55:57  AUD/USD 0.78418 0.78359
9 2018-02-25 21:55:57  AUD/USD 0.78418 0.78359

$`2018-02-25 21:56:17`
              aud_time aud_pair aud_bid aud_ask
10 2018-02-25 21:56:17  AUD/USD 0.78429 0.78367
11 2018-02-25 21:56:17  AUD/USD 0.78429 0.78367

$`2018-02-25 21:56:18`
              aud_time aud_pair aud_bid aud_ask
12 2018-02-25 21:56:18  AUD/USD 0.78418 0.78359

$`2018-02-25 21:56:21`
              aud_time aud_pair aud_bid aud_ask
13 2018-02-25 21:56:21  AUD/USD 0.78418 0.78359
14 2018-02-25 21:56:21  AUD/USD 0.78418 0.78359

$`2018-02-25 21:56:47`
              aud_time aud_pair aud_bid aud_ask
15 2018-02-25 21:56:47  AUD/USD 0.78417  0.7835

$`2018-02-25 21:56:55`
              aud_time aud_pair aud_bid aud_ask
16 2018-02-25 21:56:55  AUD/USD 0.78417  0.7835

$`2018-02-25 21:56:59`
              aud_time aud_pair aud_bid aud_ask
17 2018-02-25 21:56:59  AUD/USD 0.78429 0.78358
18 2018-02-25 21:56:59  AUD/USD 0.78429 0.78358

$`2018-02-25 21:57:00`
              aud_time aud_pair aud_bid aud_ask
19 2018-02-25 21:57:00  AUD/USD 0.78445 0.78368
20 2018-02-25 21:57:00  AUD/USD 0.78445 0.78368
```

Comment: That is a good trick. My data set is  quite large. Any other strategies that can make my calculations go faster?

Comment: would you know how to roll-up/down to the nearest 10 seconds?

Comment: Perhaps a `data.table` solution would be faster. Feel free to try that. Also, what kind of time frames are we talking about? Seconds, minutes, hours? @cephalopod